# site rendering differently on different hosts

Tags: .htaccess, server-side, host, mod-pagespeed

I have spent the last few hours trying to figure this out but still no luck...I think I have narrowed it down as something to do with a file permission issue on my host but maybe someone on here would be so kind as to point me in the right direction.

I have exactly the same files loaded onto two different domain, host combinations

1. http://northern.uwcs.co.uk/ApricotGum
2. http://apricotgum.co.uk

site a. renders fine but exactly the same files uploaded to site b. render in a very different way breaking most of the sites layout.

some of the problems with site b:
FlexSlider navigation does not work.(*edit* this is fixed by turning off mod-pagespeed with ?ModPagespeed=off# ***)
Variety of layout problems.
Animations on the top logo do not work.

Please note the site is designed for mobile content...

Many thanks

Comment: The two URL in your question gave me two completely different websites. Look at the source and you'll find they have almost nothing in common. As far as I'm concerned only the DOCTYPE is the same. Was it edited?

Comment: sorry Bart, this was solved a couple of days after I had posted the question and as a result the files were updated on one server and not the other, thanks for trying none the less.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS are different. In Chrome Dev Tools, there are noticeable differences between styles from `W.main.css.pagespeed.cf.4qEnpEHvwU.css` and `main.css`.

E.g. `.header` in `W.main.css.pagespeed.cf.4qEnpEHvwU.css`:

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

In `main.css`:

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: width 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 0.25em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Andrey I hadn't seen the different css references before.

Im guessing the second host has mod-pagespeed installed hence the change in css but when trying "?ModPagespeed=off" in the URL the site still doesn't render correctly am I missing something else in the URL maybe another caching mod?

Comment: I do not see any problems when using `?ModPagespeed=off`.

Comment: The about us section social media icons are displayed incorrectly, the favicon has not been updated and also the contact us form at the bottom still has layout issues

Comment: EDIT after turning it off in the .htaccess file the file does appear to render ok, still the favicon issue but minor problem...

Will I be able to reactivate the ModPagespeed once the site is complete without any problems?

Comment: _Will I be able to reactivate the ModPagespeed once the site is complete without any problems_ I do not know, you probably should ask separate questions about any specific problems with `ModPagespeed`.